# The test:run command is missing, but other commands work fine

Tags: testing, console

I installed Drupal Console, put it on my path, ran `drupal init`, and  successfully used Drupal Console to generate a module.

Now I want to run tests with `drupal test:run`, but I get this error.

> [ERROR] Command "test:run", is not a valid command name.

`drupal` lists many commands, but it is missing the ones for tests. This is a sample of the list.

```
 state
  state:delete (std)                      Delete State
  state:override (sto)                    Override a State key.
 taxonomy
  taxonomy:term:delete (ttd)              Delete taxonomy terms from a vocabulary
 theme
  theme:download (thd)                    Download theme in application
  theme:install (thi)                     Install theme or themes in the application
  theme:path (thp)                        Returns the relative path to the theme (or absolute path)
  theme:uninstall (thu)                   Uninstall theme or themes in the application
 update
  update:entities (upe)                   Applying Entity Updates
  update:execute (upex,updb)              Execute a specific Update N function in a module, or execute all
 user
  user:create (uc)                        Create users for the application
  user:delete (ud)                        Delete users from the application
```

Why are the commands for tests missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Drupal Test module, then run drupal cache:rebuild, and command test:run will appear.